# What does it mean to have a zero-dimensional induced metric?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions

I have an integral on the form
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^dx g_{\mu \nu} h^{ab}.
\end{equation}

In this example, $g_{ab}$ is a $d$-dimensional metric, $h_{ab}$ is an co-dim 2 induced metric. I wanted to conside what would happen with the above integral for $d=2$. But this means that $h_{ab}$ would be a zero dimensional metric. I am not sure conceptually what this means. Does it mean that $h_{ab}$ is just a number, namely the value of the point it is induced on?
But if I substitute in a point the indices in the above equation is not right anymore?

Comment: A one-dimensional metric is just a number. The reason is that there's just one coordinate then, say $\tau$, and only one component $h_{\tau\tau}$. A zero-dimensional metric just makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A metric" is an object that takes two vectors and gives a scalar, in a bilinear and symmetric way. For GR, the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ takes two 4D vectors. You are considering a case where $g_{\mu\nu}$ takes two 2D vectors, you have a codimension $2$ submanifold (i.e. a collection of points), and so the induced metric $h_{ab}$ on that submanifold takes two 0D vectors. (Contrary to the comment,) This makes perfect mathematical *sense*, but you don't get anything useful. The tangent space at each point of the submanifold is just the 0D vector space $V=\{\vec0\},$ and the only bilinear (symmetric) function $h:V\times V\to\mathbb R$ is $h(\vec0,\vec0)=0.$ The indices $a,b$ have *no* valid values (whereas for $g$ the indices range $\mu,\nu=1,2$) and $h_{ab}$ has *no* components (because there's no freedom at all in its behavior). If you tried contracting $h_{ab}$ against vectors $v^a,u^b$ you would just get the empty sum $h_{ab}v^au^b=\sum_{a=1}^0\sum_{b=1}^0h_{ab}v^au^b=0$ (since $h_{ab}$ has no components, $v^a$ has no components, $u^b$ has no components). The bottom line is that every formula will make sense, but will also degenerate to zero.

I suspect you won't get much physical intuition on this route.